# Accessing a shared mail box through imaplib4 which has no password

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, outlook, imaplib

I'd want to gain access to a Generic Mail Box (Shared Mail Box) and retrieve the attachments from an unread email. The problem is that the mail box does not have a password, however imap.login(user, password) requires a password.

```
with MailBox('imap.outlook.com').login('abc@domain.com', "") as mailbox:
    for msg in mailbox.fetch(AND(seen=False)):
        for att in msg.attachments:
            print(att.filename, att.content_type)
            files.append(att.filename)
            with open(path) as f:
                f.write(att.payload)
```

The given code works flawlessly for password-protected accounts. Please let me know if there is an alternate way of downloading the attachments using python from a no password mail box.

Thanks.

Comment: Which library are you using here? `MailBox` is not a standard Python module. It's unclear what you mean by a "no-password mail box"; usually you need a user name and a password to log in to any IMAP server.

Comment: Hi, I am using imaplib4, There is a shared mail box from where I need to download the attachments. This shared mal box doesnt have a password

Comment: I can't find a library with that name, link please? Usually simply put an empty password like you already do; doesn't that work? Which IMAP server?

Comment: There is no way it doesn’t have some security.  Otherwise, anyone would be able to login to `imap.outlook.com` and retrieve your email (assuming that’s not a fake address).  If it’s intended to be used as a delegated or shared mailbox, these are not generally well supported in IMAP.  You would have to log in as a real user, then switch to the shared mailbox…. and MS doesn’t seem to document how to do that very easily.  If you can help it, using Outlook’s REST APIs may get you a lot farther.

Comment: @Max just wanna add that it is indeed more common than you'd like to believe that mailboxes don't have passwords, they're usually used for internal mailboxes within an org network. I've seen it many times, and it's not necessarily a security-risk nor unusual.